# Trying to script partitioning Macintosh HD in command line?

Tags: hard-drive, macos, command-line, disk-utility, partition

I am trying to script partitioning the `Macintosh HD`. I am running

```
diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk0 GPT JHFS+ New 100g
```

in command line and I'm getting this error.

```
Started partitioning on disk0
Unmounting disk
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
(Is a disk in use by a storage system such as AppleRAID, CoreStorage, or APFS?)
```

So it seems like it's having problems dismounting `Macintosh HD` because that's what my laptop is running on. How do I partition `Macintosh HD` while booted on it?

diskutil list

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB       disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB       disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            499.4 GB       disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB       disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +499.1 GB       disk1
                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             EFDB0B2F-EEBB-4CAC-8AFE-69F4C1803A54
                             Unlocked Encrypted
```

diskutil coreStorage list

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 5E012656-B5D2-43E3-999F-5EF2E2D0C138
=========================================================
Name:         Macintosh HD
Status:       Online
Size:         499418034176 B (499.4 GB)
Free Space:   10645504 B (10.6 MB)
|
+-< Physical Volume 404807DA-ADE9-4CAE-B449-279488379018
|   ----------------------------------------------------
|   Index:    0
|   Disk:     disk0s2
|   Status:   Online
|   Size:     499418034176 B (499.4 GB)
|
+-> Logical Volume Family 78187C7A-2A55-48A1-AEE3-25AD3A9E3538
    ----------------------------------------------------------
    Encryption Type:         AES-XTS
    Encryption Status:       Unlocked
    Conversion Status:       Complete
    High Level Queries:      Fully Secure
    |                        Passphrase Required
    |                        Accepts New Users
    |                        Has Visible Users
    |                        Has Volume Key
    |
    +-> Logical Volume EFDB0B2F-EEBB-4CAC-8AFE-69F4C1803A54
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Disk:                  disk1
        Status:                Online
        Size (Total):          499055067136 B (499.1 GB)
        Revertible:            Yes (unlock and decryption required)
        Revert Status:         Reboot required
        LV Name:               Macintosh HD
        Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
        Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

diskutil apfs list

```
No APFS Containers found
```

Comment: Are you executing the script as root?  Have you tried it from the Disk Utility app to see if it will even let you?

Comment: When you say executing the script as root, does that mean appending a sudo to the command? If so, yes. I know it's possible because I can do it in disk utility, I just want to script it.

Comment: What is the (notable) output of the following:   diskutil list;   diskutil coreStorage list; diskutil apfs list;

Comment: Updated above with desired outputs

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? "partitioning the Macintosh HD" is like baking an already baked and portioned piece of cake (disk1/Macintosh HD) or garnish millet flour (disk0s2/LVG/Macintosh HD)

Comment: I need a case sensitive partition on my Macbook for my code, so I'm looking to partition off of Macintosh HD a dev partition for my code to live on.

Comment: You cannot use the _verb_ `partitionDisk` when you've booted from the target of that _verb_! You'd have to boot from an external source, e.g. a macOS USB install flash drive in order to use `partitionDisk` on the internal disk. Read the man page for `diskutil`.

Comment: You have two possibilities: you can resize the LV  EFDB0B2F-EEBB-4CAC-8AFE-69F4C1803A54 and create a second logical volume **in** the LVG. Or you can resize the whole LVG and create a fourth "normal" partition at the end of the disk - which one do you prefer? Each can be performed booted to your system volume. Do you want to encrypt the case-sensitive dev volume?

Comment: Just wanted to note that my first comment "You cannot use the _verb_ `partitionDisk` ..." is just an FYI and not meant to tell you what you who do. You should do as klanomath suggests, he is extremely good with this type of scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your main disk is already partitioned. You can't use `diskutil partitionDisk /dev/disk0 GPT ...` booted to the same disk.

---

In my opinion you have three options:

1. Resize the current Logical Volume "Macintosh HD" and create a second logical volume in the LVG
2. Resize the whole stack and add a fourth volume at the end
3. Create a growing sparsebundle image in your encrypted volume "Macintosh HD"

---

1. Resize the logical volume:

   - resize the logical volume:

     ```
     diskutil cs resizeVolume EFDB0B2F-EEBB-4CAC-8AFE-69F4C1803A54 399055m
     ```
   - add a second logical volume in the free LVG space:

     ```
     diskutil cs createVolume 5E012656-B5D2-43E3-999F-5EF2E2D0C138 jhfsx "dev" 100%
     ```
   - Result:

     ```
     /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB       disk0
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB       disk0s1
       2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            499.4 GB       disk0s2
       3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB       disk0s3

     /dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
       0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +399.1 GB       disk1
                              Logical Volume on disk0s2
                              EFDB0B2F-EEBB-4CAC-8AFE-69F4C1803A5
                              Unlocked Encrypted
     /dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
       0:                  Apple_HFS dev                     100.0 GB       disk2
                              Logical Volume on disk0s2
                              C7C75FC4-4062-42E7-B2F5-576CFCA257854
                              Unencrypted
     ```
2. Resize the stack:

   - resize the whole stack:

     ```
     diskutil cs resizeStack EFDB0B2F-EEBB-4CAC-8AFE-69F4C1803A54 399055m
     ```
   - add a fourth volume with [gdisk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gptfdisk/) (download required)

     ```
     sudo gdisk /dev/disk0

     Enter the following key sequence: N/Enter/Enter/Enter/AF00/W/Y Check the help with `?`!
     ```
   - format case-sensitive after getting the new device identifier

     ```
     diskutil list
     sudo newfs_hfs -v dev -J -s disk0s4 #use the appropriate device identifier here
     ```
   - modify volume permissions with chgrp/chmod if necessary
   - Result:

     ```
     /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB       disk0
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB       disk0s1
       2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            399.4 GB       disk0s2
       3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB       disk0s3
       4:                  Apple_HFS dev                     100.0 GB       disk0s4        
     /dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE           IDENTIFIER
       0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +399.1 GB       disk1
                              Logical Volume on disk0s2
                              EFDB0B2F-EEBB-4CAC-8AFE-69F4C1803A5
                              Unlocked Encrypted
     ```
3. Create a growing sparsebundle:

   ```
   hdiutil create -type SPARSEBUNDLE -size 100g -fs JHFS+X -volname dev dev
   ```

   Check `man hdiutil` for other formats like SPARSE etc.

---

Scripting this is rather difficult but not impossible - except the last proposal which is easy to implement.

Comment: I second the sparsebundle, especially for code.  Very easy to back up, to move to another machine, etc., without having to partition a drive.